# A platform of wild animals to be shown to the public

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-choice

I was writing an essay, and when I finished it and read it, I thought that this sentence:

> Zoos have always been the platform of wild animals to be shown to the public.

Is not idiomatic at all. But I don’t know a better way to put it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

> Zoos have always been the platform **for** wild animals to be shown to the public.

This is grammatically acceptable, but it is still wrong - there are other ways of showing wild animals to the public, e.g. wild life parks, game reserves, national parks. So you may wish to amend this sentence to something like:

> Zoos have always been the **main** platform **for** wild animals to be shown to the public.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by James to use **for** is correct and is also the least "invasive" change. But there are a number of ways to restate your sentence.

> Zoos have always been the platform for wild animals to be shown to the public.

In speech you could empasize **the** and pronounce it like "thee"; in writing you can italicize to indicate such prosody:

Zoos have always been *the* platform for wild animals to be shown to the public.

Emphasizing **the** in that manner has the meaning "the preferred platform" or "the most widely used platform".

You could also say:

Zoos have always been *the* platform for showing wild animals to the public.

Zoos have always been *the* platform to show wild animals to the public.